# Difficulties to correctly apply a htaccess RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've got this code in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /testsite/
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*) administrator/$1
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /^administrator/
RewriteRule ^administrator/(.*) admin/$1 [L,R=301]
```

---

**Working**

My actual URL is: `http://localhost/mysite/administrator/`

When I type `http://localhost/mysite/admin` it's retrieving the correct page.

---

**Failing**

When I try to request the page using `http://localhost/mysite/administrator/`, it should apply a rewrite to `http://localhost/mysite/admin`, but no avail.

Seems that redirecting is working, but rewriting isn't.
Any help on this?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? i got the same need :)

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /mysite/

RewriteRule ^administrator /admin [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that you have a stray `^` in your `RewriteCond` matching THE_REQUEST before "administrator":

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /^administrator/
```

To:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /administrator/
```